# Is long promise causing NodeJS App to fail readiness checks?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform

I currently have an asynchronous function that takes ~7 minutes to complete. It works fine running on a localhost node server, but fails readiness checks on Google App Engine after ~6 minutes and causes the app to restart (503 status on readiness check).

The structure of the function is like this:

```
await Promise.all(customers.map(customer => recursivelyDownloadProfiles(someRequestParams)));

const recursivelyDownloadProfiles = (request, profiles = []) =>
    downloadProfilesAndReturnNextPage(request).then(
        ([nextRequest, moreProfiles]) => {
            const allProfiles = [...profiles, ...moreProfiles];
            if (!nextRequest) {
                return allProfiles;
            }
            return recursivelyDownloadProfiles(nextRequest, allProfiles);
        }
    );
```

Each page downloaded has a 5 second 'sleep' timeout to stay within API quotas.

I'm trying to understand the issue - is this 'non-blocking' code? so even if my recursion was infinite (which it is not), why is the readiness check failing?

#### update

Looking at readiness check logs, they send 200 on each iteration until after about 6 minutes, then they start failing at some iteration. Is something to do with http requests blocking readiness checks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revisited this open bug and found my answer: This was an Out of Memory error on my instance. Turns out the recursive downloading of profiles had reached 1.25GB of RAM and the instance shut down each time.

After ruling out TIMEDOUT requests with logging, I then went to the app engine console and found this telling graph: 
[image: Memory Profile]

Of course, this wasn't an issue on my personal machine.

This was confirmed by logging the size of my array in bytes on my local machine.

**Solution**
This was simply overuse of the spread operator when downloading paginated results from a 3rd party API. 
Instead of using `const cumulativeProfiles = [...cumulativeProfiles, ...newlyDownloadedProfiles]` I used `cumulativeProfiles.push(newlyDownloadedProfiles)`, which over 80 pages, makes a huge memory difference